# This is inefficient, how can I loop instead?

Tags: javascript, html, tin-can-api

I'm trying to pull down two verbs and their associated statements and this code works but I recognize that it is inefficient. I tried putting the verbs in an array then referencing the array item in each line where the verb is named but that threw an error. What code can I use to make this loop through a verbs array that I build? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Get 2 verbs</title>
        <script src="xapiwrapper.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='demo'></div>
        <script>

                var text = "";
                ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({"endpoint":"https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/"});            
                var search = ADL.XAPIWrapper.searchParams();
                search['verb'] = ADL.verbs.completed.id;
                search['since'] = "2017-08-08T08:34:16Z";
                var res = ADL.XAPIWrapper.getStatements(search);
                if (res) {
                    text = JSON.stringify(res);
                    }              

                var text2 = "";
                ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({"endpoint":"https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/"});            
                var search = ADL.XAPIWrapper.searchParams();
                search['verb'] = ADL.verbs.resumed.id;
                search['since'] = "2017-08-08T08:34:16Z";
                var res = ADL.XAPIWrapper.getStatements(search);
                if (res) {
                    text2 = JSON.stringify(res);
                    }   

            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text + text2;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you think that this code is inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this instead?  Untested of course.

```
var configs = [
  {
    endpoint: 'https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/',
    verb: ADL.verbs.completed.id,
    since: "2017-08-08T08:34:16Z"
  },
  {
    endpoint: 'https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/',
    verb: ADL.verbs.resumed.id,
    since: "2017-08-08T08:34:16Z"
  }
];

var out = '';
configs.forEach(function(cfg) {
  ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({"endpoint":cfg.endpoint});
  var search = ADL.XAPIWrapper.searchParams();
      search['verb'] = cfg.verb;
      search['since'] = cfg.since;
  var res = ADL.XAPIWrapper.getStatements(search);
  if (res) {
    out += JSON.stringify(res);
  }
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can return a list of statements using either verb in a single request, that's not supported by the standard XAPI search. You will need to make multiple requests and merge the two sets of statements at your end.